# Count folders in list

Tags: list, web-part, folder

I am not able to count folders in SharePoint 2010 list using code, Below is my code

```
protected DataTable GetMonthlyFSSCReportDataTable(string month, string month1) // Added by Chandan 09/02/2015
        {
            try 
            {
                //Create a Table
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                //Define Table Columns
                dt.Columns.Add("RequestId", typeof(String));
                dt.Columns.Add("CreatedOn", typeof(String));
                dt.Columns.Add("CreatedBy", typeof(String));
                dt.Columns.Add("ApprovedOn", typeof(String));
                dt.Columns.Add("ApprovedBy", typeof(String));
                dt.Columns.Add("CompletedOn", typeof(String));
                dt.Columns.Add("CompletedBy", typeof(String));
                dt.Columns.Add("Duration", typeof(String));

                //Add a Row to show description for Headers

                dt.Rows.Add("Request Id for Request",
                            "Request Created Date & Time",
                            "Request Created By",
                            "Date and Time when Request Status changed from Pending Approval to Pending Setup",
                            "Request Status changed from Pending Approval to Pending Setup By",
                            "Date and Time when Request Status changed from Pending Setup to Complete",
                            "Request Status changed from Pending Setup to Complete By",
                            "Duration between the change of Request status from Pending Setup to Complete");


                SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
                {
                    using (SPSite mySite = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Site.Url))
                    {
                        using (SPWeb myWeb = mySite.OpenWeb())
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                //string month = "2013/11";
                                string currentMonth = Convert.ToString(dtcRequestDateFrom.SelectedDate);  //Commented by Chandan 06/02/2015 for new requirement to filter the record between two dates


                                string toMonth = Convert.ToString(dtcRequestDateTo.SelectedDate); // Added by Chandan 06/02/2015


                                string firstDateOfMonth = Convert.ToDateTime(currentMonth).ToString("yyyy-MM-01"); //Commented by Chandan 06/02/2015

                                string toDateOfMonth = Convert.ToDateTime(toMonth).ToString("yyyy-MM-01"); // Added by Chandan 06/02/2015

                                SPList AuditMasterList = myWeb.Lists[Constants.AUDIT_MASTER];
                                SPQuery query = new SPQuery();

                                //query.Query = "<Where><Geq><FieldRef Name='Created' /><Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>2014-01-01</Value></Geq></Where>"; //Commented by Chandan 06/02/2015

                                query.Query = "<Where><And><Geq><FieldRef Name='Created' /><Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>" + firstDateOfMonth + "</Value></Geq><Leq><FieldRef Name='Created' /><Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>" + toDateOfMonth + "</Value></Leq></And></Where>"; // Added by Chandan 06/02/2015

                                query.ViewAttributes = "Scope=\"Recursive\"";

                                //query.ViewAttributes = "Scope='RecursiveAll'";
                                //SPList list = myWeb.Lists["Audit Master "];



                                SPListItemCollection folders = AuditMasterList.GetItems(query);

                                lblError.Text = Convert.ToString(folders.Count);
                                foreach (SPListItem folderItem in folders)
                                {
                                    SPFolder folder = folderItem.Folder;
                                    SPQuery folderQuery = new SPQuery();
                                    folderQuery.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Request_x0020_ID' /><Value Type='Text'>" + folder.Name + "</Value></Eq></Where>";
                                    folderQuery.ViewAttributes = "Scope=\"Recursive\"";
                                    SPListItemCollection allitemsInFolder = AuditMasterList.GetItems(folderQuery);

                                    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                                    bool flag = false;
                                    DateTime PendingSetUp_Time = DateTime.Now;
                                    DateTime Complete_Time = DateTime.Now;

                                    foreach (SPListItem item in allitemsInFolder)
                                    {

                                        DateTime requestChangedTime = Convert.ToDateTime(item[Constants.REQUEST_CHANGED_TIME]);
                                        if (month != Constants.SELECT)
                                        {
                                            //Check if Request Created month is same as provided month
                                            if (requestChangedTime.ToString("yyyy/MM").Equals(month))
                                            {
                                                dr["RequestId"] = Convert.ToString(item["Request ID"]);


                                                    if (item[Constants.REQUEST_PREVIOUS_STATUS] == null)
                                                    {
                                                        if (item[Constants.REQUEST_NEW_STATUS] != null)
                                                        {
                                                            if (item[Constants.REQUEST_NEW_STATUS].ToString().Equals("New"))//Created By & Created On
                                                            {
                                                                dr["CreatedOn"] = Convert.ToDateTime(item[Constants.REQUEST_CHANGED_TIME]).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm tt");
                                                                dr["CreatedBy"] = item[Constants.REQUEST_CHANGED_BY].ToString();
                                                                flag = true;
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                    else
                                                    {
                                                        if (item[Constants.REQUEST_PREVIOUS_STATUS].ToString().Equals("Pending Approval") && item[Constants.REQUEST_NEW_STATUS].ToString().Equals("Pending Setup"))//Approved By & Approved On
                                                        {
                                                            dr["ApprovedOn"] = Convert.ToDateTime(item[Constants.REQUEST_CHANGED_TIME]).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm tt");
                                                            dr["ApprovedBy"] = item[Constants.REQUEST_CHANGED_BY].ToString();
                                                            PendingSetUp_Time = Convert.ToDateTime(item[Constants.REQUEST_CHANGED_TIME]);
                                                            flag = true;
                                                        }
                                                        else if (item[Constants.REQUEST_PREVIOUS_STATUS].ToString().Equals("Pending Setup") && item[Constants.REQUEST_NEW_STATUS].ToString().Equals("Complete"))//Completed By & Completed On
                                                        {
                                                            dr["CompletedOn"] = Convert.ToDateTime(item[Constants.REQUEST_CHANGED_TIME]).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm tt");
                                                            dr["CompletedBy"] = item[Constants.REQUEST_CHANGED_BY].ToString();
                                                            Complete_Time = Convert.ToDateTime(item[Constants.REQUEST_CHANGED_TIME]);

                                                            TimeSpan duration = Complete_Time.Subtract(PendingSetUp_Time);//(PendingSetUp_Time-Complete_Time);
                                                            dr["Duration"] = string.Format("{0} Days,{1} Hours,{2} Minutes, {3} Seconds", duration.Days, duration.Hours, duration.Minutes, duration.Seconds);

                                                            flag = true;
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                    if (flag)
                                    {
                                        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex) { SPDiagnosticsService.Local.WriteTrace(0, new SPDiagnosticsCategory(Laird.App.AVL.Constants.AVL_LOG_TITLE, TraceSeverity.Unexpected, EventSeverity.Error), TraceSeverity.Unexpected, ex.Message, ex.StackTrace); }
                        }
                    }
                });

                return dt;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                SPDiagnosticsService.Local.WriteTrace(0, new SPDiagnosticsCategory(Constants.AVL_LOG_TITLE, TraceSeverity.Unexpected, EventSeverity.Error), TraceSeverity.Unexpected, ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: You might need to be more specific. A wall of code won't get you much help I'm afraid.

Comment: I am very sorry Bunzab.. :(

i have sharePoint list, Inside of list there is various folder . i want to count the folder, how many folders in list?. but i am not able to do that.., when i am debugging i am getting folders count zero(null). I am finding null values in this line [lblError.Text = Convert.ToString(folders.Count);] when i am debugging, So can u provide me code to count the folder and after count controls need to goes inside of loop, But now after checking null folder it came out of loop.  so plz provide me

Comment: No worries. folders.count will only show a count of the folders collection. It will not take into account any children. You will need to check for folder.subfolders and count each until subfolders is null. Make sense?

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint List does not have folders, Document Libraries does.
As an Example:

```
using (SPSite oSite = new SPSite("url"))
{
    using (SPWeb oWeb = oSite.OpenWeb())
    {
        SPDocumentLibrary oDoc = oWeb.Lists["list_name"] as SPDocumentLibrary;
        int numFolders = oDoc.Folders.Count;

        if (numFolders > 0)
        {
            foreach(SPFolder folder in oDoc.Folders)
            {
                foreach (SPFile file in folder.Files)
                {
                    SPListItem oItem = file.Item;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will acces to each Item in each folder in your document library

Comment: hi marco thanx a lot.!!